# Is it ok to mix CL4 memory with CL5?

Tags: memory, latency

I have 2 x 1GB on 800Mhz CL4 memory in my PC.  I'm planning to upgrade to 6GB by adding a pair 2GB modules.

Is it ok if I buy CL5 modules or do I have to buy CL4?

Comment: What operating system are you using?
You should be aware that you need to run a 64-Bit system to support more than 3,5GB of RAM.

Comment: I plan to upgrade to windows 7 64bit

Comment: i have just done the same and pc is running ok , 2x1GB CL4 Sticks and added 2x2GB CL5 Sticks , just trying to research these settings i think the sticks have different stats ex 5-5-5-18 i think the newer ones are less so not sure if i have to alter settings in bios or not :-)

Comment: Not true on two counts.
1) a 32 bit OS can use way more memory with PEA.
2) The 3.5GB is not 3.5GB but 4GB minus PCI[e] address space. It is often rounded to 3.5GB but it can be more and it can be way less. 3.5 is a nice average though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, should be fine, but all will run at CL5.